# how to suppress Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator in findbugs?

Tags: java, annotations, warnings, findbugs

How to suppress " Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator"  and "Unread field" warning ?

I don't want to / rather can't change some implementation so how could I pass/suppress this warning ?

Please tell me what all package I need to import including annotations.

Thank you.

Comment: jars can be found at - http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings

and Annotations to be used --> 

@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("URF_UNREAD_FIELD")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate a class/method/field with [`@SuppressFBWarnings`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html) and the bug to ignore from the [FindBugs bug descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) list.

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings;

class MyBuggyClass
{
    @SuppressFBWarnings("URF_UNREAD_FIELD")
    private int unreadField;

    @SuppressFBWarnings("WMI_WRONG_MAP_ITERATOR")
    public void useKeySet() { ... }
}
```